# negative number result printing from roll

Tags: c++, dice

I know the title is kind of vague but im building a program to roll dice (as you've all seen in courses forever) what is confusing me is the result im getting with my output.

I'm only rolling one six-sided die and im counting the occurences of each face. my result prints how id like in list form, however if when i tell the program to roll say 30 times, the result i receive is -858993460. I have no idea as to where it might come from and i hope someone could give me an idea of where i went wrong, ill post my header and source file code, some of it is incomplete in certain areas where i have left comments.

```
//Dice.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
```

using namespace std;

```
class aDie {
public:
    aDie();
    int Roll();
    int getRoll();
    void setRolls(int r);
    int getTotal();
    void setTotal(int t);
    int numOnes = 0, numTwos = 0, numThrees = 0, numFours = 0, numFives = 0, numSixes = 0;
    int rollTotal();
    int Display();
    int numRolls;
    int allRolls = 0;
    int randomRoll;
protected:
    int roll;
    int totalRoll;
    int DisplaySomeRolls;

};

aDie::aDie() {

}

int aDie::getRoll() {
    return roll;

}

void aDie::setRolls(int r) {
    roll = r;
}

int  aDie::getTotal() {
    return  totalRoll;
}

void aDie::setTotal(int t) {
    totalRoll = t;
}

int aDie::Roll() {
    //roll the dice here
    return 0;
}

int aDie::Display() {
    int DiceFaces[6]  { numOnes, numTwos, numThrees, numFours, numFives, numSixes };

return DisplaySomeRolls;
    //use this to display the outputs of each face
}

// ProjectNumberTwo.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Dice.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    aDie getRolls;
    aDie DiceFaces[6];
    int  numRolls    = 0;
    int  rollTotal   = 0;
    int  numOnes     = 0, numTwos = 0, numThrees = 0, numFours = 0, numFives = 0, numSixes = 0;
    int  randomRoll  = rand() % 6 + 1;


    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    cout << "How many rolls? "; // GEt user input of how many rolls
    cin >> numRolls;
    cin.ignore();


    cout << "**Dice Roll Statistics***" << endl;

    getRolls.setRolls(numRolls);


    if (numRolls >= 1) {  // Rolls dice numRolls times
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) //makes a for-loop that makes an array of all the rolls from the user input
            DiceFaces[i].setRolls(randomRoll);

        numRolls = randomRoll;

        if (rollTotal == 1) { // Count number of occurences 1-6
            numOnes += 1;
        }
        else if (rollTotal == 2) {
            numTwos += 1;
        }
        else if (rollTotal == 3) {
            numThrees += 1;
        }
        else if (rollTotal == 4) {
            numFours += 1;
        }
        else if (rollTotal == 5) {
            numFives += 1;
        }
        else if (rollTotal == 6) {
            numSixes += 1;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        cout << i << ": " << DiceFaces[i].Display() << endl;


    // The printout needs to be rollFaces so it prints how many times the face  
    // happened, not getroll which only shows one single roll

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `DisplaySomeRolls` is never set. Your output is simply the default value it takes, which could be anything.

Comment: Your code is very disorganized. The number of rolls to make is placed into an object that's supposed to be one die, and then completely ignored. No matter how many rolls are entered, the code always makes only 6 rolls. Then, it takes a completely different `int` that's always initialized to 0, and then compares it to numbers 1 through 6. What all of this is supposed to mean, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: So i would have to set it equal to each roll value for the faces before it prints, right?

Comment: What you have to do is have [a long conversation with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), and work together on figuring out what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Well, i know what i need it to do in my head, but this approach is difficult for me to execute. Whats the best way to organise it? I'm essentially teaching myself so my understanding isn't the best

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing this:

`numRolls = randomRoll;`

Also, look at what you are setting the Die rolls to and when you are making the random roll assignment.

Honestly, the logic that you are using seems much more complicated than it needs to be.  Your code is naive enough for me to suggest that you start from the beginning (no offense).  Write some code to assign 10 dice rolls to your counters, and then expand from there, (DON'T BE AFRAID OF THE DEBUGGER).

I hope this helps some.

Comment: None taken, ive started over a handful of times while making this because i dont like how its working. Im essentially teaching myself so my logic isnt there.

Comment: I think that Sams' suggestion is a very helpful one for you.  Start out simple. 1) print out 10 different dice rolls.  2) Create your 6 counters and assign them the 10 dice rolls results. 3) Start studying how this gets placed into a class. 4) Dont leave home without your Rubber Ducky.

Comment: Thank you, ill bring him with me wherever i go

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS AND LET ME KNOW IF IT WORKS FOR YOU OR NOT !

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class dice
{
public:
    int a,z=0,y=0,x=0,w=0,v=0,u=0;
    void number_generation()
    {
        a=rand()%6+1;
    }
    void checkcount(int t)
    {
        if(t==1)z++;
        else if(t==2)y++;
        else if(t==3)x++;
        else if(t==4)w++;
        else if(t==5)v++;
        else u++;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"OCCURENCE OF EACH NUMBER IS AS FOLLOWS:\n";
        cout<<"1-"<<z<<endl<<"2-"<<y<<endl<<"3-"<<x<<endl<<"4-"<<w<<endl<<"5-"<<v<<endl<<"6-"<<u<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    int i,throws;
    dice d;
    cout<<"Enter the number of throws";
    cin>>throws;
    for(i=0;i<throws;i++)
    {
        d.number_generation();
        d.checkcount(d.a);
    }
    d.display();
}
```